# Session getting disconnected in the middle of working

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Sessions are getting disconnected automatically (in the middle of working).

Disconnection happens for the users when they working by using telnet connection to Linux server via putty telnet application.

During the disconnection, the Network b/w utilization is high and no limitation for total number of users in a network.

Error "Hangup signal received (562)"

Any idea about this ??

Answer (score 0):

The network connection was interrupted or a hangup signal was sent via "kill".

You mention network utilization being "high" when disconnects happen.  How do you know that?  What measurement are you looking at that tells you it is "high"?  That might be a symptom of a networking issue that is at the root of the problem.

Comment: hi Tom thnks for the reply ,whenever the user getting disconnected from their sessions ,I can able to see "Hangup signal received(562)" in database log file.moreover the sessions getting disconnected for some users randomly not all the members. so I dont think it is network issue. still dont know what is that erro and which side the problem resides.please get me out of this ..

Answer (score 0):

There are few directions:

1. OpenEdge has published this article with links to implementing keep-alive packets:
   https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Telnet-connection-times-out-after-15-minutes
2. Increase the number of "instances" in xinetd.conf, and then restart the service.
3. Make sure that the database watchdog is up and running: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmadm/prowdog-command.html
4. Check the database log file, to find out what happened just before the hangup (https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/gsins/openedge-database-log-file.html)